# Ways to find what is leaking WDFMEMORY objects in a driver?

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, driver, wdk, wdf

I'm working with a Windows kernel driver (written with [WDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/)) that I'm not the author of, but I have access to the source code. That driver seems to leak kernel memory over time that eventually causes a BSOD.

So while analyzing a full memory dump after a BSOD, I ran:

```
!wdfdriverinfo drvr.sys 0x41
```

that showed an unusually high number of the `WDFMEMORY` objects - almost 20k.

I'm wondering if there's an automated way to find out what is causing this memory leak? (Aside from the static code analysis.)

Comment: If you can enable driver verifier that would help. Otherwise you can look at pool allocations and see what stands out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-poolused

Comment: @Luke: thanks. What option in the verifier would you suggest for that?

Comment: I don't have it in front of me but there's an option you can set that will track allocations (including source location) and trigger a bsod on driver unload if there are any outstanding allocations.

Comment: @Luke you know I tried `!poolused 3` but nothing really stands out. Are WDF objects included in the `poolused` output though?

Comment: All allocations should be included. I don't know what tags WDF uses.

Answer (score 1):

`!wdfpoolusage` debugger extension would be useful to you debugging pool related issues.  For more info, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-wdfkd-wdfpoolusage

Comment: Thanks. This seems like what I need. Although it gives me an error that "Framework is not tracking pool usage for this driver". And I'm working with a crash dump.

Comment: The documentation says it only works if KMDF verifier is enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/using-kmdf-verifier If verifier wasn't enabled when the crash dump was generated then you're not going to get anything out of it.

Comment: @c00000fd if this is helpful, please mark this post as Answered for others' benefits